# Why is my function producing additional new lines?

Tags: c, printf

I am having a `function`, which should only accept valid inputs.
In this case a valid input would be an `integer` value greater
zero and smaller `UCHAR_MAX`.
In case of an invalid input is should throw the [ERR]-message
in a new line. The problem hereby is that while ist works the
way it should by characters, it does not work the way it should
when the values are outside of the defined range `(0 < input < UCHAR_MAX)`.
That means when the input is something like -42 or 1337 it makes after
the [ERR]-message an additional line an waits for another "enter".

Why does it make an additional new line, waiting for another "enter", while it works by characters and how can i overcome this problem?

```
int get_int(void)
{
  char lsc;   // least significant char - stores the last char at scanf()
  char correct_input = 'f'; // boolean value to exit the while-loop
  int input = 0;            // stores the users input
  int return_value = 0;     // stores the return value of scanf();

  while (correct_input == 'f') {
    printf("Please enter an unsigend integer value greater zero: ");
    return_value = scanf("%d%c", &input, &lsc);

    if (return_value == 2 && lsc == '\n' && UCHAR_MAX > input && input > 0)
    {
      printf("[OK]  Valid input.\n");
      correct_input = 't';
    }
    else if (return_value == EOF) {
      exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
      printf("[ERR] Invalid input!\n");
      while(getchar() != '\n');    // flushes the scanf()-buffer
    }
  }
  return input;
}
```

**Resulting output:**

```
Please enter a unsigend integer value greater zero: foo
[ERR] Invalid input!
Please enter a unsigend integer value greater zero: 1337
[ERR] Invalid input!

Please enter a unsigend integer value greater zero: -42
[ERR] Invalid input!

Please enter a unsigend integer value greater zero: 5
[OK]  Valid input.
```

As you can see above it makes additional new lines, when the value is outside the range.

I am grateful for any help, links, references and hints!

Comment: You "flush" even when there is nothing to flush. So when you input a number followed by newline, the program waits for one more newline. I'll recommend `fgets` and `sscanf` instead of `scanf`

Comment: In the case of the `foo` input, no newline was read, in the case of `1337` input, it has.

Comment: Why do you need '&lsc' in `scanf()`?

Comment: @H.S. It is needed so that inputs like `3bar` are invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So why does it produce a new line when the value is outside the range?

It does not produce one more new line; it waits for you to input one because of the `while(getchar() != '\n')`.

> how can i overcome this problem?

Skip the `while(getchar() != '\n')` if the newline has already been read by `scanf()`.

```
      if (return_value < 2 || lsc != '\n')  // do only if \n not already read
      while(getchar() != '\n');    // flushes the scanf()-buffer
```

Comment: Well now I see the problem, your approach worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`while(getchar() != '\n');` makes your program to wait for enter key

Comment: Thats true, but it does its job in case of an string/char input like `foo` or `3bar`. So why does it produce a new line when the value is outside the range?

Comment: Its because if you enter `foo` your scanf fails,as the first value should be integer. So `foo` is still left in the buffer and your `getchar()` in while consumes the `foo` + newline after `foo` and breaks the loop. similarly for `3bar` 3 is stored in `input` and `b` is stored in `lsc` and the balance `ar\n` is left over in buffer and consumed by `while(getchar() != '\n');` and breaks after reading newline. But for `1337` the value is stored in `input` and the newline(because of enter key) is stored in `lsc`. Now nothing will be left in buffer so it waits for input in `while(getchar() != '\n')`